# How can I ensure [innerHTML] content is fully rendered before running a .js function in Angular?

Tags: angular

```
    declare function gsapProcedure(): any;  
         // this function is from the .js file which is in index.html
         // I'm sure this function can work 
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-escrowProcedure',
      templateUrl: '
                     <div [innerHTML]="respVo.htmlContent| safe:'html'"></div>

                   '
    })
    export class Component implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor(
        private commonService : CommonService
        private dataService: GetPostDataService,
      ) { }

      vo = new respVo;

      ngOnInit(): void {
          this.commonService.initForm();

          this.dataService.getPostData(null, procedure, (data) => {
          if (isEmpty(data)) {
            return;
          }

          if (data.status_code == SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE) {
            this.commonService.copyProperties(data, this.vo );
          } else {
            this.dialogService.notify("", data.message);
          }
        });
      }
      ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        gsapProcedure();
        // this function content : use jquery to controll the DOM 
        // like 'let examples =  $('.example')...'
   
      }
    }
```

i tried so many way and this is one of them .
But it seems that the [innerHTML] rendered after the ngAfterViewInit() function
and there is nothing in examples  (let examples =  $('.example')...)
how can i fix it 
like make sure the content of [innerHTML] is completely rendered and then do the function
so that i can get the dom with jquery selector in the js function

** i know it is bad to use jquery in angular project 
but i can't make the decision in this project.

Comment: Constructor is called first. You can try calling your method there instead of ngAfterViewInit()

Answer (score 0):

When you change the variable "respVo.htmlContent" ?

Is when you change the variable, enclosed in a setTimeout you can call to your function, e.g.

```
dataService.getData().subscribe(res=>{
   respVo.htmlContent=res;
   setTimeout(()=>{
      gsapProcedure()
   })
})
```

But I don't see the subscribe in your code. If your `this.dataService.getPostData` is calling to a httpClient.get it's an async function, so you can not return the result of the call in anyway.

Remember: "the services return observables, we subscribe in components"